# How can I make a touchable opacity when another touchableopacity is clicked and set the text in it to the value entered in a text input

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm a 13-year-old beginner to react native, and I need help with the problem in the title.

I need to do that all on a touchable opacity click. I have tried searching for other solutions on google but found nothing.

It's actually a tutorial on `Youtube`.

Here is the link: [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uLHFPt9B2Os)

Please help me.

Thank you.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Header from './components/header';
import TodoItem from './components/todoItem';

export default function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([
    { text: 'turn on laptop', key: '1'},
    { text: 'create an app', key: '2'},
    { text: 'play on the switch', key: '3'}
  ]);

  const addToDo = () => {
    
  }

const PressHandler = (key) => {
    setTodos((prevTodos) => {
      return prevTodos.filter(todo => todo.key != key);
    });
}


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Header />
      <View style={styles.content}>
        {/* todo form */}
        <View style={styles.list}>
          <FlatList 
            data={todos}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <TodoItem item={item} PressHandler={PressHandler}/>
            )}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
        <TextInput style={styles.todoInput} maxLength={20} onChange={() => this.setState} />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.submitTodo} onPress={addToDo}>
          <Text style={styles.submitTodoText}>Done</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1, 
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
  },
  content: {
    padding: 40,
  },
  todoInput: {
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 1, 
  },
  todoInput: {
    height: 31,
    borderColor: "coral",
    borderStyle: "dashed",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 10,
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 26,
    width: "73%",
    textAlign: "center",
    marginLeft: 25,
  },
  submitTodo: {
    padding: 10,
    width: "15%",
    position: "absolute",
    right: 15,
    bottom: 26,
    backgroundColor: "coral",
    borderRadius: 10,
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  submitTodoText: {
    color: "#fff",
    fontSize: 10,
  }
});
```

Again Thank you, for spending time on this.

Comment: Please add minimal code snippet